# Getting the result of a MySql query order by date when the date field can contain strings differents than dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a date field on my Sql table that is actually a text field, thats because there sometimes I save dates like *10/28/2011* and sometimes strings like *present*.

[image]

It is possible without touching the table structure, and maybe just with the sql query having the result correct organanized by date? Where *present* is the max value and then the dates in decreasing order.

Comment: you must be joking! Fix that DB! Don't use string types to represent a date.

Comment: Isn't this the reason that nullable `DATE` columns exist?

Comment: when you request a query you can request is from a view where you have replaced `present` with the current date, or something like that.

Comment: change present to today date . it will be benefit in future also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't sort the data type out on those string date columns then this might help:

```
select t.*,
case when date_end = 'present' then curdate()
else convert(concat(substr(date_end,7,4),'-',substr(date_end,1,2),'-'    ,substr(date_end,4,2)),date) end as "realDate"
from myTable t
order by "realDate" desc;
```

Right. I'm off to go and say 100 Hail Marys to the MySQL database god now. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

`select job_desc, data_begin, data_end from table where data_end = 'present'
union
select job_desc, data_begin, cast(data_end as date) data_end from table where data_end <> 'present' order by data_end desc`

Not sure if syntax is completely correct, so you might want to check the mySql 'union' syntax

Another solution might be using coalesce for 'present':

`select cast(coalesce(data_end,now()) as date) data_end from table order by data_end desc`

this way the column gets interpreted as dates and 'present' gets replaced with the present date

Comment: that's not going to work because the final `order by data_end` is still just sorting a text column. as text, the rows end up in a different order than as dates.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '_desc' in 'field list'

Comment: i read _desc from your print screen as column name. i meant the first column in the print screen. can't read the entire name

Comment: ok, so with '_desc' i meant 'job_desc' :-) changed it in code, but i just picked some columns. I don't know what columns you'll need in your query but it's important that if you use the 'union' query, you select the same columns in both selects.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be :

- fix the db and add proper date fields (add proper date or datetime field and update values from text fields and format them to be dates on the fly)
- keep your present status in a text field and you can use that as a extra condition

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a way to sort it correctly as a text column, but I really don't think that's the right way to this.

I agree with @stivlo. It is very easy to update the database to deal with this is a better way. You can either:

- Convert the column to a real date, and use `NULL` to represent "present" instead of the string "present".
- Or, if you need `NULL` reserved for some other meaning, you can convert the column to a real date, and add additional boolean flag columns to specify when the dates are "present".

Either way, you should definitely convert those text fields to real dates.